# How do i prevent my div from being wider than the rest of the page

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a stubborn div that wont respond to anything i try. It is a gallery displaying images. It shows normal on larger screens but when i switch to mobile, it looks awful.the other components respond normally.

I have tried combinations and combinations, with no results. any help would be appreciated.

test website https://www.kottage.house/

[image: mobile view]

[image: desktop view]

```js
import {
  Card,
  CardMedia,
  CardContent,
  Typography,
  CardActionArea,
} from "@mui/material";
import cardStyles from "../styles/ShowCabins.module.css";

const ShowCabins = ({ images }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Typography className={cardStyles.heading}>
        Rent a room or the whole place
      </Typography>
      <div className={cardStyles.container}>
        <div className={cardStyles.album}>
          <img className={cardStyles.img} src="yellowCabbin.jpg" />
          <div>
            <div className={cardStyles.description}>
              <h1>Fall Cabbin in Alaska</h1>
              <p>
                Beautiful cabin in Alaskan country side by a river. Quiet place
                and abudance of nature ready to be explored by you and your
                family
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={cardStyles.album2}>
          {images.map((image) => (
            <Card
              key={image.id}
              className={cardStyles.card}
              sx={{ maxWidth: 320, m: -0.2 }}
            >
              <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                  style={{ maxHeight: "14vh" }}
                  className={cardStyles.img}
                  component="img"
                  key={image.id}
                  image={image.url}
                  alt={image.id}
                />
                <CardContent>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      color: "black",
                      margin: "0px",
                      padding: "0px",
                      textShadow: "none",
                      bottom: "-1rem",
                    }}
                    className={cardStyles.description}
                  >
                    <p>{image.id}</p>
                  </div>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ShowCabins;
```

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-height: 40vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 80vw;
    padding-top:16px;
    margin: 0px 120px 0px 120px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: brown;

}
.img{
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.album{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0px;
}
.album2{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    padding: 0px;
}
.card{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 0px;
    max-width: 19vw;
    margin-left: 10px;   
}

.img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.3);
    z-index: 1;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your body put :

```
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for min-width's?

E. g. the min-width of .ShowCabins_container is 500px.